# GCC __builtin_ functions

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Are the following functions executed in a single clock cycle?

```
__builtin_popcount
__builtin_ctz
__builtin_clz
```

also what is the no of clock cycles for the ll(64 bit) version of the same.
are they portable. why or why not?

Comment: __builtin__popcountll and similar which work on 64 bits.

Comment: Clock cycle depends on the CPU architecture.

Comment: Just a note: your question title implies that those functions are built into c++. they are not, they are specific to your compiler.

Comment: what is the general behavior? I mean is there a CPU instruction which provide these inbuilt features or do they loop on each bit?

Comment: @PlasmaHH does that mean certain compilers do not provide them?

Comment: See here: http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=36630

Comment: No compiler other than GCC will provide them unless it does so for compatibility with GCC.  Some (mainly older) versions of GCC may not provide the functions.  They are probably available on all platforms (though I'm not certain of that), and make optimal use of system resources for the task that the function does.

Comment: @Kriateive: It mostly means that only a single compiler provides them

Comment: Re. portability, C++20 introduces functions in the [bit header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/bit) which return a similar result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Do these functions execute in a single clock-cycle?**

Not necessarily. On architectures where they can be implemented with a single instruction, they will typically be the fastest way to compute that function (but still not necessarily a single clock cycle). On architectures where they cannot be implemented as a single instruction, their performance is less certain.

On my processor (a Core 2 Duo), `__builtin_ctz` and `__builtin_clz` can be implemented with a single instruction (Bit Scan Forward and Bit Scan Reverse). However, `__builtin_popcount` cannot be implemented with a single instruction on my processor. For `__builtin_popcount`, gcc 4.7.2 calls a library function, while clang 3.1 generates an inline instruction sequence (implementing this [bit twiddling hack](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel)). Clearly, the performance of those two implementations will not be the same.

**Are they portable?**

They are not portable across compilers. They originated with GCC (as far as I know), and are also implemented in some other compilers such as Clang.

Compilers that do support these functions may provide them for multiple architectures, but implementation quality (performance) is likely to vary.

`__builtin` functions like this are used to access specific machine instructions in a somewhat easier way than using inline assembly. If you need to achieve the highest performance and are willing to sacrifice portability to do so or to provide an alternate implementation for compilers or platforms where these functions are not provided, then it makes sense to use them. If optimal low level performance is your goal you should also check the assembly output of the compiler, to determine whether it really is generating the instruction that you expect it to use.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a first idea of what your compiler does with it by compiling it with `-O3 -march=native -S` into assembler code. There you can check if this resolves to just one assembler statement. If so, this is not a guarantee that this is done in one cycle. To know the real cost, you'd have to measure.